# How to cast a JSON DateTime to actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

My `json.start` returns `2012-12-21 10:02:35`

I try `var start:Date = json.start as Date;` and get a `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

- use a DateFormatter object: [DateFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html)
- use a regular expression and build a Date object: [RegEx](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=12_Using_Regular_Expressions_03.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
var start:Date = DateFormatter.parseDateString('2012-12-21 10:02:35');
```